# Use for loop to get i:i+1 columns

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, julia

I want to use `for` loop so I can get the result for  i:i+1 columns at each iteration. E.g: when  i= 1, I get 1st & 2nd cols, i= 2 , 3rd and 4th cols.

```
m= [2 -3;4 6]
al= [1 3;-2 -4]
l=[1 0; 2 4]
Random.seed!(1234)
d= [rand(2:20, 10)  rand(-1:10, 10)]
Random.seed!(1234)
c= [rand(0:30, 10)  rand(-1:20, 10)]
n,g=size(w)
mx=zeros(n,2*g)  
for i =1:g 
 mx[ : ,i:i+1] = m[:,i]' .+ (d[:,i]' .* al[:,i])' .+  (l[:,i]' .* c[:,i]) 
end
return mx
```

I got the following which is wrong when I compared it with doing the process manually

```
julia>  mx
10×4 Array{Float64,2}:
  8.0  -6.0  10.0  0.0
 22.0   3.0  18.0  0.0
 40.0  18.0  38.0  0.0
  9.0   9.0  22.0  0.0
 51.0   3.0  18.0  0.0
 10.0  18.0  34.0  0.0
 52.0  12.0  30.0  0.0
 36.0  21.0  42.0  0.0
 44.0  24.0  42.0  0.0
 33.0  24.0  42.0  0.0
```

The first 2 cols and last 2 cols in mx should be matched  the results here  with same order

```
mx1_2=m[:,1]' .+ (d[:,1]' .* al[:,1])' .+  (l[:,1]' .* c[:,1])                         
mx2_4=m[:,2]' .+ (d[:,2]' .* al[:,2])' .+  (l[:,2]' .* c[:,2])
```

Comment: Maybe `for i = 1:(g/2)` and use `(2*i - 1):(2*i)`? (Don't use Julia much, so there may be a much better way, but mathematically that should work to get 1&2, 3&4, ...)

Comment: in your code you are overwriting the same columns (firstly 1 and 2 but then again 2 and 3 so the previous value gets overwritten.

Comment: @GregorThomas I kept `for i =1:g` and changed `i:i+1` to `(2*i - 1):(2*i)` and it works!